# How important is it to keep OAuth's access token secret?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0

Once I receive my access token for a site (say facebook) using OAuth, how important is it to keep this secret? Could anything malicious happen if someone got a hold of one?

I was wondering if it would be a bad idea to save the token in a cookie or session.

Comment: You might not want to store in a cookie, but a session is OK. The idea is that cookies are considered "user input" and are unreliable (unless using signed cookies), which means you'd technically have to query your user database to validate that the access token is valid before using it. That is already done for session IDs at the session level in most web frameworks.

Comment: Aside from validity I am more worried about security. So I took the access_token I got from facebook and on a different computer ran curl -F 'access_token=162032318056|2.0r19NN8CJ3qiz2e0dA_G6w__.3600.1288576800-6423201|q7GD-dWTEvWoqEZjZ77Ga_ddhwA' -F 'message=TEST' https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed         This command posted TEST on my wall. So I am worried about a malicious user being able to read someones cookies, grab the access token they got from a site, and then being able to run privileged commands on someones facebook account. From this test it looks like that is possible

Comment: Brad, did you figure out a solution? Aside from session or a cookie, where else would store it? Saving it in DB each time user logs in and then querying it seems like a cumbersome idea at best...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update: if you are having the user connect with the javascript sdk, the user id and access tokens are already be stored in cookies for your site.  Check the http cookies being sent.  If they are not, check the [FB.Init](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.init) documentation, as FB.Init has a cookies boolean parameter you can set so that it will create a cookie for you named fbs_{APPID}.  [This](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) post talks about that cookie.

Comment: It seems like once I get the access_token I do not need any other keys to do privileged things.. Ill mess around with it more I guess. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the access token is equivalent to your username/password.  Most implementations will expire the access token after a time but while it is still valid it must be kept a secret.