# iOS - Venmo API integration: Web Redirect URL

Tags: ios, redirect, venmo

I'm trying to register my App on Venmo's developer site so that I can properly use their API, but I'm stuck trying to figure out what the required "Web Redirect URL" field is for.  According to the docs, it says it is the following:

> Venmo will redirect your users to this address. Must be formatted like
>   http(s)://www.example.com/example_redirect_url

As far as I could gather this was a URL scheme that would allow Venmo to redirect you back to your app after payment processing was completed on their side, but in researching how to set up a URL scheme the format is something like "[scheme-name]://", not "http://...."

The other thought I had was that this was just a url that contained a server-side or javascript redirect to that aforementioned URL scheme, but that seems like an unnecessary extra step.  I also have a few other theories on what it could be, so I'm really just not sure which one it is...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [On a high level, how does OAuth 2 work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4727226/on-a-high-level-how-does-oauth-2-work)

Answer (score 1):

I was running into the same problem. If your website is deployed you can use the redirect that your hosting service provides you. If you're not deployed then you can set it localhost.

Example: http://localhost:8000/auth/venmo/callback