# Example Spring Social OAuth2

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I'm researching about OAuth2 in Spring MVC. Could you please help me a simple example for OAuth2 between Sping security with Facebook or Google. Thank you!

Comment: Did you consider using spring social? If so, this might be of help: https://github.com/naturalprogrammer/spring-boot-security-social-sample

Comment: check this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4727226/on-a-high-level-how-does-oauth-2-work/43900145#43900145

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/oauth-20-beginners-guide