# How oAuth 2 works?

Tags: authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0, authorization

I have gone through [On a high level, how does OAuth 2 work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4727226/on-a-high-level-how-does-oauth-2-work) but i have still some specific
questions how oauth 2 works

Here are the sequence of steps for oAuth from stated link

1. Site-A registers with Site-B, and obtains a Secret and an ID.
2. When User tells Site-A to access Site-B, User is sent to Site-B where he tells Site-B that he would indeed like to give Site-A permissions to specific    information.
3. Site-B redirects User back to Site-A, along with an Authorization Code.
4. Site-A then passes that Authorization Code along with its Secret back to Site-B in return for a Security Token.
5. Site-A then makes requests to Site-B on behalf of User by bundling the Security Token along with requests.

My questions are about below points :-

**1) Authentication :-** which step and how it is happening.  No one explained how authentication actually happens here

`My Understanding on this point:-` From `William Jones` answer looks like it is happening at step 2. If yes how its happening ? I believe its happening with
the help of cookies(which are sent automatically when url is hit from same browser instance like jsessionid for java based app if user is already logged in and if not service
provider asks for credentials explicitly ). Is that correct ?

**2) Authorization Code :-**  I am not sure whats the use of the use authorization code here. Why not site-B can straight away give the security token.
I mean why step 4 and step 2 can't be merged where sita presents secret code and authenticated data through cookies and site B presents the security token

**3) Security/Access Token :-** My understanding is once security token is shared, Site B will share the info just based on that.Say Site A has got Security token number as 100 from Site B for user X. Now if user Y of Site A gets some security token (i understand
its probably not possible to sniff  as its on SSL), then he can access the public info of user X

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are describing one of the Protocol Flows referred to as the Authorization Code Flow.

There are four "Actors" in OAuth 2.0.

- Resource Owner - (End User)
- OAuth Client (WEB Application)
- Authorization Server Facilitates for Resource Owner and Resource
  Server and issues tokens (Maybe the same server as Resource Server)
- Resource Server - Holds the Protected Resources (Owned by Resource
  Owner)

Often the OAuth Client, Authorization Server and Resource Server all the same machine or in the Same Domain. How Communication between the  Authorization Server and Resource Server is performed is not really specified by OAuth 2.0.

> 1) Authentication :- which step and how it is happening. No one
>   explained how authentication actually happens here
>   Remember[OAuth 2.0 is not an authentication protocol.](http://oauth.net/articles/authentication/)
>
> 2) Authorization Code
>   Your steps are not well defined. Try looking through at the [Grant Type: Authorization Code](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-oauth-2) with pictures.
>
> 3) Security/Access Token
>   Not Shared. Issued by Authorization Server and presented to Resource Server by way of the OAuth Client.

Comment: For point 1 here is my question:- stackoverflow uses facebook oauth for authentication/authorization ? When i am looged in facebook, i can directly log in to SO (i just have to say i want to use FB login) and when i am not logged in FB, it ask me credential. So i wan to understand that process . I believe it happening step 2 . I am not sure is it part of oauth or some separate protocol ?

Comment: @jwillwkw see my related question http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271623/how-stackoverflow-uses-facebook-login.  If you can answer that, it will be more clearer