# Oauth2 for Aurelia hosted in asp .net core

Tags: .net-core, aurelia

My setup is:

- aspnet core site hosting a Aurelia app
- aspnet core api

I can easily config the hosting asp core site to do the auth with oauth2.

How can I pass a token to the hosted Aurelia app so it will be used for requests to the api?

Answer (score 2):

EDIT:
Get an OAuth token using standard flow: [On a high level, how does OAuth 2 work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4727226/4780928)

Pass it to the Aurelia client as a result of the API call to log in, or whatever.  Should be done via https, ideally.

ORIG:
You need to add an `Authorization` header to the request.

(Assuming you're using [`Aurelia-Fetch-Client`](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/fetch-client/latest/http-services/2))

Presumably, you have a bearer token, so the header could be configured like so:

```
httpClient.configure(config => {
  config
    .withBaseUrl('api/')
    .withDefaults({
      credentials: 'same-origin',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'X-Requested-With': 'Fetch',
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${getTokenFromLocalStore()}`
      }
    })
```

where `getTokenFromLocalStore` is your function that returns the token you  retrieved earlier.

Comment: That is true, but how do I obtain this token in the first place? I am not suer about the flow of data here.