# HTTPS REQUEST WITH stream_context_create()

Tags: php, curl, authentication, https

I have problem with my code, the error I get is:

> **Warning: fopen(https://discordapp.com/api/v6/auth/login): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 BAD REQUEST in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\s2.php on line 15**

Here is the relevant Code:

```
<?php
$data = array("email" => 'Email@gmail.com', "password" => 'Password');
$data_string = json_encode($data);                                                                                   
$context_options = array (
        'https' => array (
            'method' => 'POST',
            'header'=> "Content-type: application/json\r\n"
                . "Content-Length: " . strlen($data_string). "\r\n",
                 'content' => $data_string

            )
        );

$context = stream_context_create($context_options);
$fp = fopen('https://discordapp.com/api/v6/auth/login', 'r', false, $context);

?>
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems directly logging in via a bot is no longer allowed as you should use the OAuth2 ([how does OAuth2 work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4727226/on-a-high-level-how-does-oauth-2-work)) functionality of Discord. This means that your bot needs to be set up inside your Discord account and then you may use token-based access on the bot to authenticate the external application against Discord. 
The change to no longer allow bot-based logins happened around the beginning of 2017 and at that point all PHP-based Discord-related Github applications stopped to be maintained. [Here](https://github.com/discordapp/discord-api-docs/issues/69#issuecomment-223886862) is a discussion and comment about banning bots with automated login and [this one](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/518) about that OAuth2 has to be used.

Read more about authentication and bots in [the Discord OAuth2 chapter](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/topics/oauth2).

If you can tell more about what you plan to achieve, maybe we can help you find a solution to your task.

---

**Previous (no-longer working) answer:**

I haven't used DiscordApp so I haven't tried this yet. Instead of sending JSON-encoded data, have you tried posting the values as FORM values to the API?

```
$postData = array(
  'email' => 'Email@gmail.com', 
  'password' => 'Password'
);
$params = array('https' =>
  array(
    'method'  => 'POST',
    'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'content' => $postData
  )
);

$context  = stream_context_create($params);

// get the entire response ...
$result = file_get_contents('https://discordapp.com/api/v6/auth/login', false, $context);

// ... or alternatively using fopen()
$fp = fopen('https://discordapp.com/api/v6/auth/login', 'r', false, $context);
```

I haven't found any docs regarding how the parameters should be passed to the `login` URI but at least that's how normal form-based logins can be used.

According to the [DiscordApp Response codes](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/topics/response-codes) a 400 may be received if either the call was not understood (non-existent function called) or the parameters were send improperly so you should find out about how to call the `login`interface with parameters using scripts.

Comment: Thx SaschaM78 !