# Create Auth0 user

Tags: auth0

I'm using [Management API V2](https://auth0.com/docs/api/management/v2#!/Users/post_users) to create users and I'm setting their password in the creation process.
After that they're receiving an invitation email to confirm their email address because I'm setting the parameter "verify_email" to true.

What I need to do is:

1. Create User
2. Send the user an invitation email so they can confirm their email
   address.
3. Giving them the option to set their own password, instead of me
   setting it in the creation process "step 1"

I looked up in the community before asking, and I found that I can trigger password reset flow upon the creation, is there any different way to do it? because this doesn't look like the correct way to do it, there should be a way to do so.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [On a high level, how does OAuth 2 work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4727226/on-a-high-level-how-does-oauth-2-work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Triggering reset password email is the right approach. You can use authentication API to send the reset password email. 
https://auth0.com/docs/api/authentication#change-password

More options are described here: https://auth0.com/docs/connections/database/password-change